# Which is faster for generating markup, jquery or php?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, css

What are the implications for generating a webpage by writing a library of functions that render markup when looking at a server-side (PHP) implementation vs a clientside (jquery) implementation?

Server-side:
The client makes the request, the server renders the mark up through running a php program, sends the markup to the client, the browser loads it and the webpage displays.

```
function makeTitle( $text ) {
    echo <<<HTML
    <style>
    #title {
    color:red;
    }
    </style>
    <div id = "title">{$text}</div>
    HTML;
}

makeTitle("This appears as red text");
```

Client-side:
The client makes a request, the javascript is sent to the client in a .html file, the client's browser renders the mark up, loads it and the webpage displays.

```
var text; 
function title(text) {
$('body').html(function() {
  return '<div id = "title">'+text +'</div>';
});
 $("#title").css("color","red");
}

title("This appears as red text");
```

Which implementation would be more efficient so that the user would have to wait less time, either for the server to run a php program or the browser to run a javascript program and in what cases would each implementation be most efficient in terms of generating static css and html?

Comment: You'd have to test it, but I suspect the server will be very, very much faster. jQuery is no speed demon, a server should have much more grunt than a single–threaded client (which might be a tablet or phone).

Comment: This all depends on the nature of the application and its intended design. This is not a question that should be answered purely on the gauge of speed/efficiency. There are trade offs on a myriad of different levels to each option.

Comment: I will edit the question to make it clear that I am not aiming to design a CMS

Comment: @rey I aim to speed up the process of designing a very minimal website through writing a library of functions that will generate html and css. Please give more feedback as to why the question should merit neglect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generating on the server will be fast, but you mentioned a request in jQuery for an .html file. Why not generate the html on the fly using jQuery? You can create a DOM element by passing the jQuery object a closed HTML tag, such as `$('<div/>')`. Here's an implementation using the example you gave.

```
function makeTitle(text) {
    $('body').append(
        $('<div/>', {
            id: 'title'
        }).css({
            color: 'red'
        })
    );
}

makeTitle("This will appear as red text");
```

If you're looking for a simple templating solution, PHP will be a good choice, but if you want to create a web application or page that will change content frequently without page refresh, I find it incredibly simple and fast to use PHP to generate the data, and jQuery to generate the markup.

Answer (score 4):

One other implication when using javascript to render markup is that your markup will be invisible to web crawlers.  Not the best way to go if SEO is a concern.

Comment: that's a very interesting point. There must be methods for sending out metadata for crawlers via ajax for a purely client-side implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I think generating markup through PHP is more reliable as if javascript is disabled on browsers than probably no markup would be rendered.

Apart from that Client machines may have different configurations which will further affect the markup generation response times. So i think markup through PHP would be more efficient.

Comment: -1 for "PHP markup generation would not take a lot of time."

Answer (score 0):

I would go with PHP. The difference in processing time would be minimal, however it would also work for customers who don't have javascript enabled and it doesn't require the overhead of having to download jQuery if it's not used elsewhere.

Comment: This was more of an argument in 2008 .. it almost like arguing support for IE6.

Comment: The question is also an argument for 2008, whether rendering a string server side or editing the DOM client side would be faster. So it seems even small performance enhancements matter to OP.

Comment: @pst many of the browsers used by folks who need assistive technologies (e.g. folks who are vision impaired) are worse than IE6 by a long yard.  I wouldn't rule out this concern without knowing more about the OP's intended app and target audience.

Comment: @Paul text-to-speech programs have a problem with dynamically changing content. True. But generating the DOM on DOMContentLoaded won't hinder them in any way.